# htaccess rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite a url from a sub-directory of the web root.

```
http://mysite.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page
```

to this (note question mark):

```
http://mysite.com/wiki/index.php?Main_Page
```

What I'm doing wrong here? (wiki/.htaccess)

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ ./index.php?$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Try commenting out your conditions and see if that makes a difference

Comment: It did, they were preventing it from working since index.php is a file. Then also the query string needed to be title=$1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two lines here got it sorted:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ index.php?title=$1 [PT,L,QSA]
```