# .htaccess rewriterule and condition

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Guys I am trying to change my url using .htaccess but getting one problem
My URL looks like this

```
www.example.com/web-search.php?q=car&limit=15
```

I want to turn it like that

```
www.example.com/web/cars/15
```

but not succeeding I don't get the problem please help me. Thanks
**Here is my .htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /web-search\.php\?q=(.*)\&limit=(.*?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^ web/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /web-search.php?q=$1&limit=$2 [L]
```

It works it I remove "web/" from the rewrite url but then url looks like

```
www.example.com/cars/15
```

which I don't want I want to add web/ also. Thanks in advance

Update 1:

This causing the problem it is above the mentioned rewrite rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /search\.php\?q=(.*)\&limit=(.*)\&siz=(.*?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?q=$1&limit=$2&siz=$3 [L]
```

Comment: possible duplicate `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6645137/htaccess-rewrite`

Comment: `RewriteRule ^ /%2/%3? [R=301,L]` line seems to be unrelevant. Try removing that and check.

Comment: @Rikesh still same thing happens

Comment: this line changes the url automatically so that's why I added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by two oversights. The first rule does not add "web" to the url. The second rule contains a rogue space between the `^` and the rest of the regex, causing it to return an error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /web-search\.php\?q=(.*)\&limit=(.*?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^ /web/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^web/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /web-search.php?q=$1&limit=$2 [L]
```

Remember to clear your browser cache before testing this, as your browser might have cached the old, wrong, redirect.

Comment: Yap it is working Thanks The problem I am getting is when I use another rewrite url above it which is same but have /search.php. Which make the conflict any suggestion for it? I updated the question